# Access TMediaPlayer.Position from separate thread

Tags: delphi

Is there a reason why a separate thread would be unable to query the Position property of a TMediaPlayer object?

I have written a Delphi DLL which is a form with a TMediaPlayer component. The application calls into the DLL at regular intervals, and these DLL calls can query the Position and Length values of the TMediaPlayer object on the DLL's form:

```
procedure TDLLForm.SongPosUpdate();
var
  new_pos: integer;
  new_len: integer;
begin
  new_pos := AudioPlayer.Position;
  new_len := AudioPlayer.Length;
end;
```

The above function works fine when called in the context of the application that loaded the DLL. If, however, the DLL creates a separate thread (subclassing TThread) and the new thread calls the same function, it gets invalid values for the Position and Length properties of the object:

```
// TTimerThread: Constructor
constructor TTimerThread.Create(F: TDLLForm);
begin
  DllForm := F;
  inherited Create(True);
  inherited priority := tpHighest;
end;


// TTimerThread: Execute
procedure TTimerThread.Execute;
begin
  while not Terminated do
  begin
    DLLForm.SongPosUpdate();
    Sleep (1000);
  end;
end;
```

Other properties of the TMediaPlayer object (e.g. AudioPlayer.FileName) can be queried successfully from the thread, but not Position/Length. Is there some reason why a TMediaPlayer would decline to reveal the correct Position/Length when not called in the context of the original thread that started playback?

Answer (score 5):

UI controls are not safe to access directly from outside of the main VCL thread.  There is no quarantee that ANY property will work correctly if queried from a worker thread.  In this case, the `FileName` property merely reads a String variable that is a member of the `TMediaPlayer` class, so that is usually safe enough, but the `Position` and `Length` properties have to send MCI commands to the media device, and that is where threading issues can arise.

Comment: Thanks, do you know of a proper way to do this? The reason for having a separate thread is to keep the DLL's activity going even if the DLL's calling application thread is temporarily blocked on some action. I previously used a TTimer to do the activity but I understand that this is a low priority event that goes through the normal VCL thread and thus can be backed up while the application is busy.

Comment: Rather than having the thread query the `TMediaPlayer` properties directly, I would probably have the parent `TForm` of the `TMediaPlayer` run a `TTimer` that queries the `TMediaPlayer` properties and stores the values in thread-safe variables that the thread can then read from. The alternative is to use `TThread.Synchronize()`, but that has issues inside of DLLs. If the main thread gets backed up (which means you are doing too much work in the main thread to begin with), chances are the media playback may get backed up anyway (unless MCI is using its own background threads for playback).

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if there are any rules that one can use to determine which controls are safe to be accessed from worker threads? For example it seems that I can update a bitmap in a TPaintBox from a worker thread. How does one know for sure which controls are thread-safe and which are not? – ukembedded 14 mins ago

Comment: *NO* VCL UI components are safe to access from outside of the main thread context.  There are things the VCL does internally that are simply not safe outside of the main thread.  The entire VCL as a whole is not thread-safe in general, expect for a few pieces that are specifically designed for threading.  Non-visual classes can be used across thread boundaries as long as you provide adequate locks in your code using critical sections, mutexes, etc.  But updating the UI from a worker thread directly is definately NOT safe (and no, updating a `TPaintBox` bitmap from a thread is not safe).

Comment: Thanks, I do indeed see problems when accessing the TPaintBox on a VCL window. If I paint the form into a VB.net control, however, by creating it using CreateParented() then experiments so far show no issues (this is a DLL so it can paint into the calling VB application's form). Would you know if this is safe, given that it's not a VCL form that is being painted into? (Ignoring the TMediaPlayer component for now, which is not vital).